# Converting lastlogontimestamp to DateTime

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a lastlogontimestamp to datetime but I have noticed for large values, I get the error Exception message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Is there a better way to do the below?

```
var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://GLOBAL.ABC.COM");
var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)({0}={1}))", 
  "samAccountName", username);
ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] { "samAccountName", "lastLogon" });
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
long lastLogon = (long)sr.Properties["lastLogon"][0];
// lastLogon is 131111471723190497 
var dtLastLogon = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastLogon);
return dtLastLogon.ToString();
```

Comment: Which one is throwing "Index was out of range"? Please provide an example of "large values"

Comment: It's the line where I get the lastLogon variable. The value is 131111471723190497

Comment: is that `long lastLogon = (long)sr.Properties["lastLogon"][0];` or `ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] { "samAccountName", "lastLogon" }); ` ?

Comment: long lastLogon = (long)sr.Properties["lastLogon"][0];

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the fact that account doesn't have to have `lastLogon` property. So the code should look like

```
// ...
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
if (sr.Properties["lastLogon"] != null && sr.Properties["lastLogon"].Count > 0)
{
  long lastLogon = (long)sr.Properties["lastLogon"][0];
  var dtLastLogon = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastLogon);
  return dtLastLogon.ToString();
}
// last logon is not set here - make something up; for example
return DateTime.MinValue.ToString()
```